# Including a CDATA field in a Service Connector

Tags: informatica, cdata, informatica-cloud

An API I am communicating with is Soap based and requires XML with inner XML (CDATA) in the request.

For the service connector action test I have hard-coded the inner xml with this format:

```
<![CDATA[   
<Application xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ApplicationCrossReferenceId="123"> 
...
...
</Application>    ]]>
```

where the dots indicate the data contained.
When running the test the request payload has been transformed to the html entity for `<` which is `$lt;` - as seen below :

[image]

Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: This exact topic was asked on Informatica's forum in 2018, but not providing any answer (despite being marked "Answered") https://network.informatica.com/thread/83388

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in Informatica. the other characters are decoded back to their original correctly, as described in [KB 512858](https://kb.informatica.com/faq/7/Pages/18/512858.aspx), &gt and &lt however are not decoded.

A bug report has been raised 29.05.2020.

Edit: Further investigation revealed that using CDATA was not necessary in my case, instead I was able to use the following input for the body binding:

```
<Application xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ApplicationCrossReferenceId="123"> 
    ...
    ...
</Application>
```